# Unable to Import solution - The dependent component SavedQuery (Id=xxxx) does not exist

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I received this error the other day when trying to import a new solution in Dynamics 365 v9.

It's the first import solution after update from Dynamics 365 V8.2 to 9.1.

> The dependent component SavedQuery
>   (Id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxyy) does not exist. Failure
>   trying to associate it with AppModule
>   (Id=yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyy) as a  dependency. Missing
>   dependency lookup type = PrimaryKeyLookup.

After racking the internet for users with similar issues, I still haven't been able to find a resolution.

Any suggestions how I can troubleshoot this issue more?

Comment: From the error message - the solution you're trying to import is expecting the SavedQuery with this Id to be present in system. I guess after upgrade of CRM it can happen that some saved queries on which the solution relies are no longer there. It would be helpful to give exact error message/if possible also the solution you're trying to import. Btw. the question as it is written right now is hard to answer unless you provide those details.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a scenario where one of the lookups on the forms in your solution is using a view as the default. This view was definitely present in the source environment. But it is not present in the target environment and the entity containing this view is not part of your solution.

Your starting point would be to check the import log and find out which entity/form/view. Once you find out which entity/view, your options are:

1. Remove the default view from the lookup on the form and retry the import.

OR

2. Add the missing entity to your solution and retry the import.

Thanks